# How can one see algorithmically-proposed similar questions once a post has already been submitted?

Tags: support, similar-questions

When composing a question there appears an Ajax/Ajaj-populated box filed with potentially similar questions. Once a question is posted however, how can one find these suggestions again?

Comment: Can you type in your question again, in the ask question page? Just don't get question banned.

Comment: @Laurel Question banned?

Comment: @Seekinganswers You get question- / answer-banned if you _post_ too many low-quality posts (questions / answers respectively). An exact duplicate is considered low-quality. Just drafting them is fine: that won't get you into any kind of trouble.

Comment: I'd first examine the right side listing for Related posts beside the posted Question.  These are frequently apt suggestions for duplicates, in my experience.

Answer (score 4):

Type your question title into the box here!

```js
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

var form = document.querySelector('form');
var output = document.querySelector('output');

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let formdata = new FormData(form);
  let params = new URLSearchParams(formdata);
  let url = form.action + "?" + params;

  req.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
    output.innerHTML = req.response["content"];
  });
  req.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
    output.innerText = "Some error happened or summat: probably CORS. ";
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.innerText = "Go directly to the target page.";
    output.appendChild(a);
  });
  req.open('GET', url);
  req.send();

  output.innerText = "loading...";
  e.preventDefault();  // presumed success, so suppress reloading page
});


});
```

```html
<form action="https://meta.stackexchange.com/search/titles">
<label>
Question title: 
<input name="title" />
</label>
<button>Fetch</button>
</form>

<output></output>
```

Judging by the URL path, and from minor experimentation: consulting the site searchbar with `is:question` added, on the “Relevance” tab, will probably give you the same results.

Comment: Any more user friendly way of doing it?

Comment: @Seekinganswers If you run the code I provided from a privileged context, or inject it directly into meta.stackexchange.com via a userscript… or just use the search bar.